# Python IMAP TypeError: 'Nonetype' Object Is Not Subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

I am using imap to check for unread emails that match a specific subject. When I receive an email from my test email, it goes just fine, but when it comes from an automatic system that I'm needing it to check the emails from, I get an error stating that `'Nonetype' object is not subscriptable.` The following is my code:

```
import imaplib, time, email, mailbox, datetime
server = "imap.gmail.com"
port = 993
user = "Redacted"
password = "Redacted"

def main():
    while True:            
        conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
        conn.login(user, password)
        conn.list()
        conn.select('inbox', readonly=True)
        result, data = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN SUBJECT "Alert: Storage Almost At Max Capacity")')
        i = len(data[0].split())

        for x in range (i):
            latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
            result, email_data = conn.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
            raw_email = email_data[0][1] #This is where it throws the error
            raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
            email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
            date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            local_message_date = "%s" %(str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
            for part in email_message.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    body = body.decode('utf-8')
                    body = body.split()
                    #Do some stuff
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the following is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "TestEmail.py", line 200, in <module>
        main()
    File "TestEmail.py", line 168, in main
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.
```

I don't understand why this would work in an email sent from a person's email, yet not work when my system emails me an alert. Is there any obvious fix to this?

EDIT: I've tried printing the `result` and `email` variables. The following was their output:

```
Result: OK
Email: [None]
```

Whereas if I test the script against an email with the same subject, but sent from my test email, `result` is still "OK", but an email is contained.

EDIT#2: I've noticed that the format of the emails are a little different. The one that is being received fine is both `text/plain` and `text/html`, whereas the one that isn't being accepted is `text/plain` with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7-bit`. How might I remedy this? If I forward the email through a filter and check the email receiving from the filter, my code works just fine. However, I would like to not have to use multiple emails for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for message sequence numbers, and fetching by uid.
If you are going to use `conn.uid('fetch')`, you must also use `conn.uid('search')`, otherwise you are searching for apples and fetching oranges.

Thus, since not all MSNs are UIDs, you are occasionally fetching non-existent messages, which is not an error, but it just won't return you anything.